# Is it only me having troubles with Chrome 2.0.172.39 on Vista SP2 and Flash 10?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

It's been a while since I've seen this problem repeat itself:

When seeing YouTube videos, they stop loading after a while. What they load seems to be related to the amount of available bandwidth.

Still, even if the bandwidth is too narrow, I expect the flash plugin to finish downloading the movie as soon as possible, but it just gets stuck.

EDIT: I can confirm that this does not happen on Firefox 3. And Google isn't much help...

Comment: I have this problem in Chrome 2.0.x on BBCAmerica.com (watching top gear, sometimes the vid gets stuck and it never comes back) and on Last.Fm which can't seem to play 2 songs in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not experienced this error myself, and none of my friends who have a similar setup, which leads me to believe your flash installation is possibly corrupt.

Try uninstalling flash off your computer using the Uninstaller released by Adobe, then reinstalling again as per the usual manner in Chrome (Install plug-in).

Adobe Flash Player Uninstaller:
http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/uninstall_flash_player.exe

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dumb as it sounds reinstalling flash solved the issue. Thanks